Continuity dependence and convergence of the renormalized $\Phi^4_2$ model
This question is continuous for the one asked here: Local solutions of renormalized stochastic PDE but it was better to ask it separetely.
Again, we are interested in the local behavior of the $\Phi_2^4$ model after applying Debussche Daprato $\phi=v+Y$: $$(\partial_r-\Delta)v=-(Y^{:3:}+3Y^{:2:}v+3Yv^2+v^3) \\\\ (1),$$ $Y^{:k:}$ are the Wick powers. We also recall that the approximate equation refers to the renormalized equation (by a mollification) of $(1)$ depending on $\epsilon.$
We denote by $T$ the maximal stopping time of $(1)$ (corresponding to $v$), can we find a family of finite stopping times $(T_\epsilon)_\epsilon$ such that $T_\epsilon$ increases to $T$ when $\epsilon$ decreases to 0, $(v_\epsilon,T_\epsilon)$ is a solution for the approximate equation, $\sup_{r\in[0,T_\epsilon]}\Vert v_\epsilon(r)-v(r)\Vert_{\mathscr{C}^\alpha}$ converges in probability to 0 ? How is this related to the continuity dependence?
Proofs or references are appreciated

You can take $T_\epsilon = L_\epsilon \wedge \inf\{t > 0\,:\, \|v_\epsilon\| \ge L_\epsilon\}$ for a sequence $L_\epsilon$ going to infinity sufficiently slowly. How slow exactly depends on details of the problem you're looking at, the norms involved, etc. In virtually all cases of interest (in particular your example and other examples of that type), $L_\epsilon = |\log\log \epsilon|$ works.

We still need to ensure thaf $u$ is also a solution, so probably we need: $T_\epsilon:=L_\epsilon \wedge \inf{r\geq 0,, \max(\Vert v\Vert,\Vert v_\epsilon\Vert) \geq L_\epsilon}$?

@mathex That depends on how you interpret the statement if $v$ blows up. My interpretation is that there may be a non-zero (but small) probability that $|v_\epsilon - v|_{\mathcal{C}^\alpha}$ is infinite, but that doesn't prevent it from converging to zero in probability...

Last question: denoting $\tau,\tau_\epsilon$ the explosion times of $v,v_\epsilon$ respectively, in the definition of $T_\epsilon,$ should we include the condition $0<t<\tau_\epsilon$ (unless we still have convergence even when it's infinite)

@mathex In all these kind of problems it's always the case that the norm diverges at the explosion time, so I'm not sure I understand what the question is or rather what difference this would make.

One last inquiry before closing this topic: how do we define the solution of the initial equation in $\phi$?

@mathex They are defined as in your question...
